# Passing get variables within the page using json

Tags: json

I am trying to pass a get variable within the same html page as the page is created in jquerymobile.js
The html contains various internal pages as provided below. Now i want to pass get variables to other page within the same html as id='page1', id='page2' etc. Can anybody help on how can i pass get or post variable within the same html?
decodeURI(getUrlVars()["type"]) is not working in this case since the data is being passed using id over page (id='page2')
Here is the code:

```
    //Page 1 within the same HTML
    <div data-role="page" id="page1">
    <div data-role="header" data-theme="b">
        <h1>Page1 Header</h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">
    //dynamic server content displayed here
    </div>
    <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed" data-theme="b">
    </div>
    </div>

    //Page 2 within the same HTML
    <div data-role="page" id="page2">
    <div data-role="header" data-theme="b">
        <h1>Page2 Header</h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">
    //Want to get some of the individual dynamic content displayed in page1 using get method in JSON
    </div>
    <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed" data-theme="b">
    </div>
```

```
I am trying to pass get variable as <a href="#page2?id=$id">Button</a> which is not working.
```

Answer (score 0):

Use following function to get the parameter value

```
function getParameterByName(name, url) {
    if (!url) {
      url = window.location.href;
    }
    name = name.replace(/[\[\]]/g, "\\$&");
    var regex = new RegExp("[?&]" + name + "(=([^&#]*)|&|#|$)"),
        results = regex.exec(url);
    if (!results) return null;
    if (!results[2]) return '';
    return decodeURIComponent(results[2].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}
```

Comment: This does not work as when i pass the url as <a href="#page2?id=$id">button<a/> it simpley ignores variable in url and pass the url as index.html/#page2.